# How to hide Navigation and Status Bars when tapped - with animation

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm trying to hide my Status Bar and Navigation bar when the view is tapped. Currently I found something that works from a previous question, but the problem is that there is no animation when hiding the bars. It just disappears.

Here is my current code in my View Controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
}
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    if self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden == true {
        return true
    }
    else
    {
        return false
    }
}
```

When I tap again, the animation works when the two bars are coming back on to the screen.

If I don't include the overrided `prefersStatusBarHidden` function, I can get the navigation bar to hide with the desired sliding animation. But the status bar is still there.

Any suggestions? Does Swift 2 have a new method that can work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Try this

```
var statusBarHidden = false

      func tapAction() {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true 
    self.statusBarHidden = true
        self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        }

     override  func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
            return  statusBarHidden
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set `View controller-based status bar appearance = NO` in the info.plist?

Comment: I just did, but it doesn't change anything for me. With or without the `prefersStatusBarHidden` function it only hides the navigation bar while the contents of the status bar are still there.